# Cannot load logistic regression models in python2

Tags: python, python-3.7, logistic-regression

I am training and storing logistic regression models in python3 using sklearn. For storing, I use the pickle module as show below

```
filename = 'models/logistic_regression/protocol_2/test/{}_pixels.p'.format(i//2)
pickle.dump(clf, open(filename, 'wb'), protocol=2)
```

Then, in another script, I am loading the models in python2. The loading is achieved with the following code

```
f = open(model_names[i//2-1], 'rb')
clf = pickle.load(f)
```

However, I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named _logistic
```

Could someone tell me why I cannot load the model? Thanks in advance